# Compare the value of two Eigen

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I have implemented a function that subtracts three vectors, and then sum up their coefficients. After that, I want to compare the coefficient but the compiler shows an error. The following is my code:

```
void update_embedding_test(Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer>* matrix_a, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer>* matrix_b, const int32 index_1, const int32 index_2, const int32 index_3, const int32 index_4, const int32 index_5, float* rate) {

auto v_1 = matrix_a->chip<0>(index_1); //get the first vector
auto v_2_a = matrix_b->chip<0>(index_2); //get the second vector
auto v_2_b = matrix_b->chip<0>(index_2); //get the third vector
auto v_3 = matrix_a->chip<0>(index_3); //get the fourth vector
auto v_4 = matrix_a->chip<0>(index_4); //get the fifth vector
auto v_5 = matrix_a->chip<0>(index_5); //get the sixth vector

auto sum_a = (v_1-v_3-v_2_a).sum(); //subtract the vectors and then sum the coefficients
auto sum_b = (v_4-v_5-v_2_b).sum(); //subtract the vectors and then sum the coefficients

std::cout << "sum_a: " << sum_a << "\n"; //e.g: -0.0268941
std::cout << "sum_b: " << sum_b << "\n\n"; //e.g: 0.0502871

if ((sum_a+1.f)>sum_b) { //compare the values
  std::cout << "sum_a>sum_b\n";
}
}
```

The error that the compiler shows is the following:

```
In member function 'void tensorflow::NegTrainWord2vecOp::update_embedding_test(Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer>*, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer>*, tensorflow::int32, tensorflow::int32, tensorflow::int32, tensorflow::int32, tensorflow::int32, float*)':
word2vec_kernels.cc:725:20: error: could not convert 'Eigen::TensorBase<Derived, 0>::operator>(const OtherDerived&) const [with OtherDerived = Eigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<float>, const Eigen::DimensionList<long int, 1ul>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<float, float>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<float, float>, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> > >, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> > >, Eigen::MakePointer>; Derived = Eigen::TensorCwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::bind2nd_op<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<float, float> >, const Eigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<float>, const Eigen::DimensionList<long int, 1ul>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<float, float>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<float, float>, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> > >, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> > >, Eigen::MakePointer> >; typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar = float](sum_b)' from 'const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cmp_op<float, float, (Eigen::internal::ComparisonName)5u>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::bind2nd_op<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<float, float> >, const Eigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<float>, const Eigen::DimensionList<long int, 1ul>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<float, float>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<float, float>, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> > >, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> > >, Eigen::MakePointer> >, const Eigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<float>, const Eigen::DimensionList<long int, 1ul>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<float, float>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<float, float>, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> > >, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> > >, Eigen::MakePointer> >' to 'bool'
 if ((sum_a+1.f)>sum_b) {
```

How can I compare `sum_a` and `sum_b`?

**UPDATE:** the problem is not computing `(sum_a+1.f)>sum_b`, but is to put it into the if (`if((sum_a+1.f)>sum_b)`). The [link](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#title64) says that `operator>()` returns an expression of the coefficient-wise == operator of *this and other. However, the question still remain... How can I put `(sum_a+1.f)>sum_b` into an `if` statement?

Comment: what is the return type of .sum()?

Comment: I cannot figure it out from the documentation https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#addd7080d5c202795820e361768d0140c but if I print for example `sum_a`, I can see its value on the Terminal (e.g: -0.0268941)

Comment: Looks like you want to use the isApprox() function. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ae8443357b808cd393be1b51974213f9c

Comment: Ha, I think you got bitten by auto + expression templates. Try changing those `auto sum_a` and `auto sum_b` into e.g. floats or doubles.

Comment: with `float sum_a = (v_1-v_3-v_2_a).sum();` I get the error `error: cannot convert to 'float' in initialization`. I get the same error with `double`.

Comment: Does `((sum_a+1.f)>sum_b)).all()` work?

Comment: Did you found the solution? I am facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

From reading the documentation the return type of `.sum()` is a `DenseBase` object. We can compare two `DenseBase` objects with a specified precision by using the `isApprox` function

See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ae8443357b808cd393be1b51974213f9c

Comment: `bool r = sum_a.isApprox(sum_b);` says that `has no member named 'isApprox'`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Apologies it looks like it returns a Scalar object. This scalar type can vary, might be worth seeing if you can specify the type of the result which should allow you to use the semantics you previously tried.